# Error message "TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not list", while code is basically same code as a working version

Tags: python

I'm a noob in programming and just started using python 3.x several days ago. Also I never proactively used this website before altough it already saved me multiple times when I was stuck, so please forgive me if my question formatting is not the best.

My goal is to read through x .csv files and plot the data I want into graphs.
The first version of the program was already working:

```
import glob
import csv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from datetime import datetime


files = glob.glob('C:\\Users\Serdar\Desktop\SEMINARARBEIT\Twitch\Twitch\Summary\*.csv')
a = "Fortnite"

listViewers = []
listTimestamp=[]


for x in range(4519):
    csv_file = csv.reader(open(files[x], "r"), delimiter=",")

    for row in csv_file:
        if a == row[1]:
            datetime_object = datetime.strptime(row[4], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
            listTimestamp.append(datetime_object)
            listViewers.append(float(row[2]))


t = listTimestamp
s = listViewers
plt.plot(t, s, 'r')

plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate() 
plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.ylabel('Viewers')
plt.title('Fortnite: Viewers over Time')
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

Here I am scanning through 4500 files and plotting a graph. No problem here. In the second program I want to take just one .csv file (it's another file with another data structure than the 4500 previous ones) and process it the same way.

Here is where i get the Error in the Title. This is the code:

```
import glob
import csv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


file = glob.glob('C:\\Users\Serdar\Desktop\SEMINARARBEIT\Twitch\Twitch\Stream\1529010392.472129.csv')
a = "Fortnite"

listViewers = []
listStreamers=[]

csv_file2 = csv.reader(open(file, "r"), delimiter=",")
for row in csv_file2:
    if a == row[1]:

        listStreamers.append(row[23])
        listViewers.append(float(row[10]))


t = listStreamers
s = listViewers
plt.plot(t, s, 'r')

plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate() 
plt.xlabel('Streamers')
plt.ylabel('Viewers')
plt.title('Fortnite: Viewers over Time')
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

I understand that I am doing something like saving a list type object in "csv_file2" while it wants String or bytes etc. But I don't know where the difference to the first code is.
Given my inexperience it probably is a trivial thing i didnt see, but my suspicion is that in the file for the second code i have "[]" as a value in some places. Could it be that this is being seen as a list? Another theory could be that the second file batch has characters like "ˆÐ" which also might be a problem?

I really am not sure though, I hope that you can help me

Answer (score 3):

The problem you're experiencing is because [glob.glob always returns a list of files](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html), which your code handles correctly in the first version of your code but not in the second. Since you specified a specific file, glob.glob returns a list containing one object. Just change your code to treat the file variable like a list and it should work fine:

```
csv_file2 = csv.reader(open(file[0], "r"), delimiter=",")
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, I did not know that glob.glob returns file lists. Strangely I'm getting a "list index out of range" error when using "file[0]" which is pretty weird since there definitely is only one file in "file". Do you know why this might be the case?       Edit: Nevermind, i tried printing "file" and it returns an empty list, this should be my problem. Now i just need to find out why it does not put the csv file into "file".